# How convert nvarchar column from a existing table to date? SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server, datetime, format, varchar

I have a table in SQL Server created like this:

```
CREATE TABLE nombres
(
     nombre varchar (200) not null,
     fecha_nac char (10) not null,
     fecha_alta char (10) not null,
)
```

I created a stored procedure to fill the table quickly. The next step is "formatting" the dates made into date format. I saw that I can use

```
SELECT CONVERT(datetime, 'a string', 100)
```

In this case I want use my column as parameter like this

```
SELECT CONVERT (datetime, select fecha_nac from nombres, 100)
```

but I get an error.

I will be thankful if I get any help

Comment: How about `SELECT CONVERT (datetime, fecha_nac, 100) from nombres`?

Comment: please provided the error and sample of what the `fecha_nac varchar` looks like

Comment: error may be that you have more than one data in table but this function do one so it makes confuse to database to do it,so u should o it for every columns

Comment: @JoachimIsaksson I had an error
The query shows "Error trying to convert a String into date/hour"

Comment: @JDaniel What format are the strings in? Could you add some sample data? I sincerely doubt it's in format `100` since that won't fit in 10 characters.

Comment: select fecha_nac from nombres this query may return more than one data so your convert doesnt work

Comment: [link] (http://img286.imagevenue.com/img.php?image=672530334_resultado_etl_122_135lo.jpg)
@JoachimIsaksson

Comment: also u need to take your inner select statement to parantheses

Comment: Could you explain me @Çağrı

Comment: SELECT convert(datetime,(SELECT dbo.nombres.fecha_nac from dbo.nombres), 101) u will writw with paranthese but pronlem is innere select staement gives more than one value  so u need to do it  for every cooumns

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
DECLARE @site_value INT;
SET @site_value = 1;
WHILE @site_value <= (SELECT COUNT(nombre) FROM nombres)
    BEGIN
        WITH MyCte AS 
        (
            SELECT fecha_nac,number= ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY dbo.nombres.fecha_nac) 
            from dbo.nombres 
        )
        SELECT convert(datetime,(SELECT MyCte.fecha_nac from MyCte WHERE number=@site_value), 101)
        SET @site_value = @site_value + 1;
    END;
```

Comment: it takes data from table and convert it your date format should be dd/mm/yyyy

Answer (score 0):

With the date format you have, (`mm-yyyy-dd`), you can do some string manipulation to get it to `dd-mm-yyyy` and then it can be parsed as a `DATE` with [format 103](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187928.aspx).

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT '11-1994-27' fecha_nac
)
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE, SUBSTRING(fecha_nac, 9, 2) + '-' + SUBSTRING(fecha_nac, 0, 8), 103)
FROM cte;

-- 1994-11-27
```

Your fecha_alta format is easier, it can be parsed right away with format 102.

```
WITH cte AS (
  SELECT '2012-1-12' fecha_alta UNION ALL 
  SELECT '1994-4-5'
)
SELECT 
  CONVERT(DATE, fecha_alta, 102)
FROM cte;

-- 2012-01-12
-- 1994-04-05
```